# How to generate unique number on every time for invoice number using javascript

Tags: javascript

Tried to generate unique number from 1000 to 500000 for invoice number using javascript.So may i choose today date with time and random number.Is it correct way? How to do it?
invoice number length should be from 4 to 6.

```
var d = new Date(); 
var t = new Date().getTime();
var randomnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 -  500000)) + 1000;
randomnum = d.getFullYear() + f(d.getMonth()+1) + f(d.getDate()) + randomnum; 
randomnum = randomnum + t;
console.log(randomnum);
```

Comment: Using date day and random is probably not collision-resistant enough.  Too high a chance of collisions.  You will want to use an incrementing id.  Although I suspect 4 to 6 digits is probably not going to be enough room to work with if you don't keep track of ids to prevent collision.  uuid generation of something compliant to RFC 4122 if you want standards compliance and something trustworthy.

Comment: @user120242: Which is best way to create invoice number unique?

Comment: Best way is to simply increment, like he says: 1000, 1001, 1002, 1003 etc. There's no need to randomize invoice numbers. They're not privacy sensitive and it would only make your administration's job that much more complicated.

Comment: @icecub: How to increment unique number?

Comment: @icecub: I am asking random number should be order and unique like 1000,1001,1002 ect...

Comment: Depends on how you save your data. You retrieve the latest invoice number from your database. Say for example you have `var invoiceNr = 1000`. Then all you have to do is `invoiceNr++;`. Which will turn it into 1001. It's not something we can give you a clear answer about without known how you store and retrieve your invoice numbers.

Comment: @icecub: Otherwise can we generate unique number between 1000 to 1000000 without duplicate?

Comment: You handle that server side. Not client side. Your server will never ever process 2 orders at the exact same time. Even if both would order at the exact same time, your server will still put one in queue and handle the other first. Then you simply use the same approach there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this function below to generate `string` ID. but I don't prefer it. you should use int increment from 1 to 500000.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {number} min 
 * @param {number} max 
 * 
 * @returns {string}
 */
const getRandomId = (min = 0, max = 500000) => {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  const num =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  return num.toString().padStart(6, "0")
};

console.log(getRandomId()); // 350845, 000845
```

This function below you can use it to generate id from 1 to 500000. like int increment in MySQL. but when number is 1 this function convert it to string 000001.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {number} num 
 * 
 * @returns {string}
 */
const getId = (num) => {
  return num.toString().padStart(6, "0")
};

console.log(getId(1)); // 000001
```

This is answer for your question. how generate unique number from 1000 to 500000.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {number} min 
 * @param {number} max 
 * 
 * @returns {number}
 */
const getRandomId = (min = 1000, max = 500000) => {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  const num =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  return num;
};

console.log(getRandomId()); // 2151, 464128
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively skip numbers completely, unless you need the easily readable human format (which it does not appear, as you are generating a non-continuous number). Use a GUID instead, I can recommend [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)

It can be used like this:

```
import v4 from "uuid/v4";
const id = v4();
```

GUIDs have a collision risk of 50% after 2.7e18 generations.

Comment: How to increment unique number using uuid? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uuid-generation?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts